# Android ViewPager, timer and asyncTask, swipe freez

Tags: performance, android-fragments, timer, android-asynctask, fragmentstatepageradapter

[image]

Hello, first of all, i'am new in android development.

I want do to a viewpager with 3 fragments visible, each fragment has a clock-timer and a list with a animated(blink) background.

Each 10 seconds i do a call to my server,after response, update all the fragments and delete the ones that i don't need.

My real question is, what is the best approach to achieve my goal, I already try several options (HorizontalScrollView, etc), and when swiping it's freezing all my UI. Normally i will have 20 different fragments.

Thanks.